# PrimeFaces datatable not refreshing correctly after an add operation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable which has add edit delete and filter operations.

All the operations are working fine on the database but the datatable is not updating correctly after an add operation.

It is updated correctly after the 1st add operation.
when I add 2nd row the datatable is updated but the row which was added first is replaced with the row which was added 2nd but in the db they are updated correctly.

similarly when I add a 3rd row the 1st row is replaced with the 3rd row.

Software stack used in the CRUD dataTable application are :- PrimeFace 3.4.2,JSF 2.1,NetBeans 7.2.1,Java 1.6.0_37 GlassFish 3.1.x,MySql 5.x

This is my code.

```
 **xhtml page**

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:head>
    <title>Prime Faces Data table</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">

        <h:messages id="messages1"/>
        <br/>

        <p:commandButton id="Addbtn" value="Add" oncomplete="AddDialog.show()" 
         update=":addform"/>                
        <br/>

        <p:dataTable id="dtusers" value="#{userdataController.retrieveData()}" 
         var="item" 
                     rows="8" paginator="true" emptyMessage="No Records Found" 
                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">

            <p:column style="width:150px" filterMatchMode="contains" 
             filterBy ="#{item.id}">
                <f:facet name="header"> Id </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:150px" filterMatchMode="contains" 
             filterBy="#{item.name}">
                <f:facet name="header"> Name </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </p:column>     

            <p:column style="width:150px">  
                <p:commandButton id="editButton" update=":editform" 
                   oncomplete="EditDialog.show()" value="Edit">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" 
                     target="#{userdataController.selectedUser}"/>
                </p:commandButton>                       
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:150px">  
                <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" update=":deleteform" 
                   oncomplete="UserDialog.show()" value="Delete">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" 
                      target="#{userdataController.selectedUser}"/>
                </p:commandButton>    
            </p:column>                 

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>   
      <p:dialog header="Add User Data" resizable="false" id="AddDialog" 
        widgetVar="AddDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
        position="center" >
        <h:form id="addform">
            <p:outputPanel id="AddDisplay">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" >

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Add Userdata
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputLabel for="Id" value="Enter Id:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="Id" value="#{userdataController.selected.id}" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="Name" value="Enter Name:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="Name" 
                      value="#{userdataController.selected.name}"/>

                    <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{userdataController.createdata}" 
                        update=":form1:dtusers :form1:messages1" value="Save"    
                      oncomplete="AddDialog.hide()" style="margin:0"/> 


                 </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
        </p:dialog>   
         //similarly dialogs for delete and edit   

        </h:body>

         </html>


      **ManagedBean**

    @ManagedBean(name = "userdataController")
    @SessionScoped
    public class UserdataController implements Serializable {

    private Userdata current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private PrimeFacesDb.session.UserdataFacade ejbFacade;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Userdata SelectedUser;

    public UserdataController() {
   }
 //getters setters for id,name and SelectedUser

  private UserdataFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
  }
  public List retrieveData() {
    List result = getFacade().findAll();
    return result;
  }

   public void create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Userdata created successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Persistence Error occured");
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have solved my problem by using the code suggested by Lawyno in the following link:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11389&hilit=dialog+open&start=20

Now the table is updating correctly after the add operation.

Comment: You should add this answer & details and accept it!

Comment: Yes, please add as a real good answer!